# creating a model using JENA

Tags: java, jena, owl, semantic-web, semantics

I am new in the semantic web field, and i'm trying to create a java model using JENA to extract classes, subclass and/or comments from an OWL file..

any help/guidance on how to do such thing would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please include what you have tried so far.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but the whole documentation is online: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I'm actually lost in how/where to start the task from? Because you know its not a normal JAVA coding!

So What i am really looking for is how to include JENA in my Project and start using it for reading and retrieving from OWL file.

again,, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with the [Jena Ontology API](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology). This API allows you to create an ontology model from owl file and then provides you access to all the information stored in the ontology as Java Classes.
Here is a quick introduction to [Jena ontology](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/). This introduction contains useful information on getting started with Jena Ontology.

The code generally looks like this:

```java
String owlFile = "path_to_owl_file"; // the file can be on RDF or TTL format

/* We create the OntModel and specify what kind of reasoner we want to use
Depending on the reasoner you can acces different kind of information, so please read the introduction. */
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);

/* Now we read the ontology file
The second parameter is the ontology base uri.
The third parameter can be TTL or N3 it represents the file format*/
model.read(owlFile, null, "RDF/XML"); 

/* Then you can acces the information using the OntModel methods
Let's access the ontology properties */
System.out.println("Listing the properties");
model.listOntProperties().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
// let's access the classes local names and their subclasses
try {
            base.listClasses().toSet().forEach(c -> {
                System.out.println(c.getLocalName());
                System.out.println("Listing subclasses of " + c.getLocalName());
                c.listSubClasses().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
   }
// Note that depending on the classes types, accessing some information might throw an exception.
```

Here is the [Jena Ontology API JavaDoc](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/package-summary.html).

I hope it was useful!